# GUI wait until BooleanVar() changes

Tags: python, user-interface, input, tkinter, wait

how can I make my Tkinter GUI wait for a change of a BooleanVar()? The BooleanVar is controlled by a distance sensor. The GUI should wait until the variable changes to False and the move on.

I tried to use a while True - loop, but as expected it disturbed the mainloop and the programm crashed.
I've also considered to use one if the methods to wait for user-input, but I can't figure out how.

Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by "wait" here, because a GUI is always in a constant state of "wait". It waits for events, and then it acts on events.

If you have a `BooleanVar` that is set somehow, you can set a trace on that variable. When the value changes, the trace will call a callback of your choice. In that callback your code can do whatever you want.

```
self.sensor = tk.BooleanVar()
self.sensor.trace("w", self.on_sensor_change)
...
def on_sensor_change(self, *args):
    print "the sensor changed:", self.sensor.get()
```